# Is my information secure when using Private Tunnel?

Tags: passwords, privacy, vpn

I am using [Private Tunnel](https://www.privatetunnel.com/) to do some tasks involving sensitive data like logging in to PayPal and online banking.

Is my data safe or can it be retrieved by other users of the Private Tunnel service?

Comment: As long as your computer hasn't been compromised and you're using an https connection, your data is as safe as it can reasonably be. The owner of the private tunnel service can see your traffic, but can't decrypt it. A more sophisticated attacker (i.e. the NSA) could have compromised the bank's SSL certificate to let them intercept their data, but that independent of using a Private Tunnel service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the refered VPN, but, if it matches what the website says, i think you're good.
The only way i'm seeing you're not safe is that if you're using a wireless connection, the data can be intercepted, it would still be encrypted, but you never know... better safe than sorry.

And as @Johnny said, if you're using HTTPS, and SSL you're safe, don't be worried.